# How to get user object using username in django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates, templatetags

I am trying to get user's profile picture in a template using their username. What I have tried:
`templatetags/users_extras.py`:

```py
from django import template
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

register = template.Library()


@register.filter(name="get_user", is_safe=True)
def get_user(username):
    return User.objects.filter(username=username).first()
```

My template:

```html
{% load users_extras %}
<img src="{{ username|get_user.profile.image.url }}">
```

My `Profile` view:

```py
class Profile(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = "users/profile.html"
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    ordering = ['-datePosted']

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = get_object_or_404(User, username=self.kwargs.get('username'))
        return Post.objects.filter(author=user).order_by('-datePosted')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(Profile, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['username'] = self.kwargs['username']
        return context
```

The url for profile page is like `path('profile/<str:username>/', Profile.as_view(), name='profile')`
But that gives error

```py
Could not parse the remainder: '.profile.image.url' from 'username|get_user.profile.image.url'
```

How can I fix this error or how can I get user object using username in django template?

Comment: why don't you just filter out user and pass it to context

Comment: yes sorry for bad question i will delete(oh I cannot delete)

Answer (score 0):

You may need to get the result of the filter in a variable.

```
{% load users_extras %}
{% with username|get_user as user %}
  <img src="{{ user.profile.image.url }}">
{% endwith %}
```

Comment: uh, sorry for dumb question. Just needed to solve work in the script not in the template. added `context['user_requested'] = get_object_or_404(User, username=self.kwargs.get('username'))` to `get_context_data` function

Answer (score 0):

No need for solving things in template. First it is a bad practive. Second there's a better way. Just edit the function `get_context_data`

```py
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(Profile, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['user_requested'] = get_object_or_404(User, 
 username=self.kwargs.get('username'))
    return context
```